# sed command not working in my bash script

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to modify php.ini with sed commands but its not working for some reason

```
sed -i 's/disable_functions = /disable_functions = system, show_source, symlink, dl, shell_exec, passthru,escapeshellarg,escapeshellcmd/g' /etc/php.ini
```

The `disable_functions` line looks like this in php.ini

```
disable_functions =
```

Can you tell what is wrong

Comment: not working mean no change or error occuring ? if there is not change, trace the sed with `=,l;` at the start of the action string to display the line number and the content of the line (buffer in fact) before the s// occuring (in this case of tracing, don't use -i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in `/etc/php.ini` there is no space after the `=`

So remove the space after `=` from `sed` as

```
$ sed -i 's/disable_functions =/disable_functions = system, show_source, symlink, dl, shell_exec, passthru,escapeshellarg,escapeshellcmd/g'
```